# Ember.js connectOutlets runs on root the moment Router is created

Tags: ember.js

I have the following ember router definition:

```
WZ.Router = Em.Router.extend
  enableLogging: true
  location: 'hash'
  showHome: Ember.Route.transitionTo 'root.index'
  root: Em.Route.extend
    initialState: 'index'
    connectOutlets: (router, event) ->
      unless router.get 'initialized'
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet 'nav', 'navbar'
        router.get('homeController').connectOutlet 'bottombar', 'bottombar'
        router.set 'initialized', true

    index: Em.Route.extend
      route: '/'
      connectOutlets: (router, event) ->
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet 'home'
```

I am using connectOutlets of the root route because I want the navigation outlets to be connected no matter which url the user enters the application.

The problem is that as soon as the router is created, the root connectOutlets fires and this is before the router has had the controllers injected via runInjections.

Everything works if I connect these outlets in a leaf route but that is not what I am after.

If I cannot use the root connectOutlets, how can I best ensure that the navigation outlets are connected no matter which url or route the user enters the app on?

Should we also disallowing connectOutlets to be overriden on a leaf route as it is fairly useless if there are no controllers etc. to connect?

**EDIT:** I got round this problem by using Ember.run.next:

```
WZ.Router = Em.Router.extend
  enableLogging: true
  location: 'hash'
  showHome: Ember.Route.transitionTo 'root.index'
  root: Em.Route.extend
    connectOutlets: (router, event) ->
      Ember.run.next @, ->
        unless router.get 'initialized'
          router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet 'nav', 'navbar'
          router.get('homeController').connectOutlet 'bottombar', 'bottombar'
          router.set 'initialized', true
    index: Em.Route.extend
      route: '/'
```

But this still seems less than ideal.  Is this a hole in the Em logic or by design?

Answer (score 1):

I generally consider the root state to be special, so I dont use connectOutlets for this state. In practice this means that the root state (which responds to URL '/'), redirects to a "home" state, inside which I would put your connectOutlets.

The upside of this is that you don't run in to the controllers-not-injected yet problem, but it also means that your "default" URL becomes something like yoursite.com/#/home if not using the History API, and yoursite.com/home if you are.

Not really ideal in either case, but at least you aren't shoehorning Ember.run.next into your connectOutlets, which seems like bad form which might bring up a slew of other issues moving forward. I suppose you wouldn't, but you are now expecting that your controllers will be injected between now and when the next run loop fires... That may or may not be the case...